# Garbage on screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed Ubuntu 23.10 VirtualBox virtual machine on Windows10 hosted computer. Sometimes screen starting is getting some garbage. Why and how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Install VBOX Guest Extensions in the Guest Machine.

Comment: Ubuntu in your VM is probably trying to use 3D acceleration and it’s not quite working out.